# trouble with iterating through values in key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wrote a function that searches through the values of an object. The key is returned when it's confirmed that the key matches the index of the value stored in the array.

eg. 19 is in index 0 in the array, and in the object, the key for 19 is 0. Since this matches, the key is returned.

However, if the value is found in the object but the index is wrong in the array, -2 is returned. Finally, when a value is not found in the object, -1 is returned.

Unfortunately, my function is not working as intended. I had a feeling the function is not recognising the values in the object as the same data type as those in the array so I used  == instead of === for the comparisons but the result is the same.

```js
const exampleObject = {
   0: 19,
   1: 20,
   2: 21,
   3: 22
};


function getKey(array, object, value) {
    for (const prop in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (object[prop] === value && array[object[prop]] == value ){
              return prop
            }
            else if (object[prop] === value && array[object[prop]] !== value ){
              return -2
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
}

console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21],exampleObject,20)) //returns -2 which is wrong as the index is correct

console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21],exampleObject,25)) //returns -1 which is correct

console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21],exampleObject,22)) //returns -2 which is correct

console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21],exampleObject,19)) //returns -2 which is wrong as the index is correct
```

Edit: I used the code from this site and adjusted it a little:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value/

Comment: `if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {` will always be true right?

Comment: @0stone0 yes. to be honest I'm not really sure about the significance of that. I copied this code and modified it a little from this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-by-its-value/

Comment: Are the keys of the object always numeric, starting at 0 and incrementing by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `array[prop]` instead of `array[object[prop]]` as `object[prop]` will return the value but you want the key.

```js
const exampleObject = {
  0: 19,
  1: 20,
  2: 21,
  3: 22
};

function getKey(array, object, value) {
  for (const prop in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (object[prop] === value && array[prop] === value) {
        return prop
      } else if (object[prop] === value && array[prop] !== value) {
        return -2
      }
    }
  }
  return -1
}

console.log(getKey([19, 20, 22, 21], exampleObject, 20))
console.log(getKey([19, 20, 22, 21], exampleObject, 25))
console.log(getKey([19, 20, 22, 21], exampleObject, 22))
console.log(getKey([19, 20, 22, 21], exampleObject, 19))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object always uses `0 - n` as keys, this can be simplified quite a bit.

So, let's assume that the object always has numeric keys, starting at `0`, incrementing by `1`.

In that case, we can define a helper array, which contains all the values of the object like so:

```js
const exampleObjectValues = Object.values(exampleObject);
```

Now, we can create a simple function using the following logic;

1. If `exampleObjectValues` does not contain `value`, return `-1`
2. Otherwise,

   1. Get the index from the input array
   2. Get the index from the `exampleObjectValues`
   3. Compare them and:

      1. If they match, return the `objectValueIndex` (step 2.1)
      2. If they don't match, return `-2`

```js
const exampleObject = {
   0: 19,
   1: 20,
   2: 21,
   3: 22
};
const exampleObjectValues = Object.values(exampleObject);

function getKey(array, value) {
    if (!exampleObjectValues.includes(value)) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      const arrayIndex = array.indexOf(value);
      const objectValueIndex = exampleObjectValues.indexOf(value);
      return (arrayIndex !== objectValueIndex) ? -2 : objectValueIndex;
    }
}

console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21] ,20)); // 1 
console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21], 25)); // -1 
console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21], 22)); // -2
console.log(getKey([19,20,22,21], 19)); // 0
```

The above will output:

```
1
-1
-2
0
```

Comment: But doesn't this loop the values twice? Which can be prevented. And the array is also looped once.